# How to set Div content with JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a JSON object of arrays What I am trying to do is To fill div dynamically

- I have a `select option` Which I am filling with All the keys of My JSON data
- In my JSON each key has a array of data as its value, I am trying to add those values to other `div`, but that's not working

**Code**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ImageData = {
    "Employ A": [
      "EmployA1.jpg",
      "EmployA2.jpg"
    ],
    "Employ B": [
      "EmployeB1.jpg"
    ],
    "Employ C": [
      "EmployeC1.jpg"
    ]
  }
  var CountersName = Object.keys(ImageData)

  let dropdown = $("#counterNames")
  dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Select Counter</option>');
  for (var i = 0; i < CountersName.length; i++) {
    $('<option/>').val(CountersName[i]).html(CountersName[i]).appendTo('#counterNames');
  }
  $("#counterNames").on('change', function() {

    var value = $(this).val();

    $(".card-header").text(value) //setting card header 
    console.log(ImageData.value) // this shows undefinded on console
    $(".list-group-item").text(ImageData.value)


  })

});
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  float: right;
}


/* Hide default HTML checkbox */

.switch input {
  display: none;
}


/* The slider */

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input.success:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #8bc34a;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <label for="counterNames">Select Counter:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="counterNames">
    </select>

    <div class="card" style="margin: 50px 0">

      <div class="card-header"></div>

      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">

        <li class="list-group-item"><label class="switch "> <input type="checkbox" class="success">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**On change of Employ `select field`** I am trying to achieve something like below

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  float: right;
}


/* Hide default HTML checkbox */

.switch input {
  display: none;
}


/* The slider */

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input.success:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #8bc34a;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">


  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card" style="margin: 50px 0">

      <div class="card-header">Employ A</div>

      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">

        <li class="list-group-item ">EmployA1.jpg <label class="switch "> <input type="checkbox" class="success">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item ">EmployA2.jpg <label class="switch "> <input type="checkbox" class="success">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**I have tried below code**

```
Object.keys(ImageData).forEach(function (k) {
                ImageData[k].forEach(function (d) {
                    console.log(d) 
                 });

            });
```

but  it is printing all values like `EmployA1.jpg,EmployA2.jpg,EmployB1.jpg,Employc1.jpg` when I am selecting any drop-down from select field,What I am trying to do is when I select `EmployA` then `EmployA1.jpg and EmployA2.jpg` should come

Comment: you said:-`I am trying to add those values to other div, but that's not working`. i am unable to see that code part in any of your snippet

Comment: @AlivetoDie `$(".list-group-item").text(ImageData.value)` check this line in my first snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the index of  the array 'ImageData' wrongly. 
write ImageData['value'] instead of ImageData.value .

Also, in following you had written wrong code, I mean :

```
  $(".list-group-item").text(ImageData.value)
```

if You want to show a list of the name of the images, use the bellow code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ImageData = {
    "Employ A": [
      "EmployA1.jpg",
      "EmployA2.jpg"
    ],
    "Employ B": [
      "EmployeB1.jpg"
    ],
    "Employ C": [
      "EmployeC1.jpg"
    ]
  }
  var CountersName = Object.keys(ImageData)

  let dropdown = $("#counterNames")
  dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Select Counter</option>');
  for (var i = 0; i < CountersName.length; i++) {
    $('<option/>').val(CountersName[i]).html(CountersName[i]).appendTo('#counterNames');
  }
  $("#counterNames").on('change', function() {

    var value = $(this).val();

    $(".card-header").text(value); //setting card header 
    console.log(ImageData[value]) ;// this shows undefinded on console
   //  $(".list-group-item").text(ImageData[value])
   var ul = document.getElementById(".list-group");
   ul_innerhtml = "";
    for (i=0; i < ImageData[value].length; i++) {
     title = ImageData[value][i];
      var ul_innerhtml = ul_innerhtml+'<li class="list-group-item">'+title+'<label class="switch "><input type="checkbox" class="success"><span class="slider round"> </span></label></li>';
    }
    $(".list-group").html(ul_innerhtml);
    
  })

});
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  float: right;
}


/* Hide default HTML checkbox */

.switch input {
  display: none;
}


/* The slider */

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input.success:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #8bc34a;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <label for="counterNames">Select Counter:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="counterNames">
    </select>

    <div class="card" style="margin: 50px 0">

      <div class="card-header"></div>

      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">

        <li class="list-group-item">
         <label class="switch "> 
          <input type="checkbox" class="success">
          <span class="slider round">
          </span>
         </label>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```